# Unbound type even with a forall

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Can someone let me know what is wrong with the forall defintion:

```
> (define #:forall (A)
 (kmp-search [pattern : (Vectorof A)]
             [text : (Vectorof A)]
             [next-offset : Integer 0]) : Integer
  3)
. Type Checker: parse error in type;
type name `A' is unbound in: A
```

Comment: When removing the last parameter it does work fine. Something must be wrong with parameter with default value.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest submitting a bug report.

In the mean time, I suggest using this syntax:

```
(: kmp-search : (All (A) (Vectorof A) (Vectorof A) Integer -> Integer))
(define (kmp-search pattern text [next-offset 0])
  3)
```